# Program gives wrong results after multiple runs

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm new to coding (sorry for coding/formatting/efficiency errors etc.).
I wrote this program that interpolates measured data and gives you back some results (like line parameters, compatibility, etc.).
I also wrote a simple GUI (sorry if It's a mess) to make it easier to use.
When I first input data and start the calculation processes, it gives the expected result. As soon as I try to input other data ( or even the same again) it returns completely wrong and strange results. I tried to clear all the fields, arrays, variables after each "iteration" of the program, but I cannot solve this problem.
Any suggestions?

```
package com.company;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


// main class
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gui q= new Gui();

  }
}
// simple GUI class w/ all global variables
class Gui {

private JTextField txts;
private JTextField items1, items3;
private JTextField items2;
private int n = 0;
private double x1[], x3[];
private double y1[], y3[];
private double sigma = 0, j = 0, k = 0, m = 0;
private double w[];
private double x2[];
private double y2[];
private double wsumx = 0, werrA = 0, werrB = 0, wsumy = 0, sumv32=0, sumv32y=0, sumv3v2=0;
private double wsumxy = 0, wsumx2 = 0, sumw = 0, sumv1 = 0, sumv2 = 0, sumv34=0;
private double sumx = 0, sumy = 0, sumxy = 0, sumx2 = 0;
private double delta = 0, A = 0, B = 0, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
private double errA = 0;
private double errB = 0;
private double chi = 0;
private double redchi = 0;
private double v3[];

//constructor
public Gui() {

    //creates a window with a basic layout
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lab Assistant V1.0");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(600, 250);

    // creates buttons
    JButton calcola1 = new JButton("Calculate");
    JButton calcola2 = new JButton("Calculate");
    JButton calcola3 = new JButton("Calculate");

    JButton canc1 = new JButton("Clear");
    JButton canc2 = new JButton("Clear");
    JButton canc3 = new JButton("Clear");


    JButton enter1 = new JButton("Enter");
    JButton enter2 = new JButton("Enter");
    JButton enter3 = new JButton("Enter");

    JButton comp1 = new JButton("Compatibility");
    JButton comp2 = new JButton("Compatibility");

    // creates labels
    JLabel sval = new JLabel("Type in y error");
    JLabel num1 = new JLabel("N° of values");
    JLabel num2 = new JLabel("N° of values");
    JLabel num3 = new JLabel("N° of values");

    // creates tabs and text fields
    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

    txts = new JTextField(20);
    items1 = new JTextField(3);
    items2 = new JTextField(3);
    items3 = new JTextField(3);

    // adds elements to each tab
    JPanel stnd = new JPanel();
    tabs.addTab("Standard", stnd);

    stnd.add(sval, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    stnd.add(txts);
    stnd.add(num1);
    stnd.add(items1);
    stnd.add(enter1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    stnd.add(calcola1);
    stnd.add(comp1);
    stnd.add(canc1);


    JPanel weight = new JPanel();
    tabs.addTab("Weighted", weight);

    weight.add(num2);
    weight.add(items2);
    weight.add(enter2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    weight.add(calcola2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    weight.add(comp2);
    weight.add(canc2);

    JPanel nonlin = new JPanel();
    tabs.addTab("Non-linear", nonlin);

    nonlin.add(num3);
    nonlin.add(items3);
    nonlin.add(enter3);
    nonlin.add(calcola3);
    nonlin.add(canc3);

    // adds all tabs to the main window
    frame.add(tabs);

    // events fot the enter button (tab 1)
    enter1.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    n = Integer.parseInt(items1.getText());
                    x1 = new double[n];
                    y1 = new double[n];

                    sigma = Double.parseDouble(txts.getText());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Y error: " + sigma);
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        String C = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter x values");
                        String d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter y values");
                        if (!C.isEmpty() || !d.isEmpty()) {
                            j = Double.parseDouble(C);
                            x1[i] = j;
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X value: " + x1[i] + "");

                            k = Double.parseDouble(d);
                            y1[i] = k;
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y value: " + y1[i]);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning! Enter a valid number.");
                        }

                    }


                }
            }

    );

    // events fot the enter button (tab 2)
    enter2.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    n = Integer.parseInt(items2.getText());
                    x2 = new double[n];
                    y2 = new double[n];
                    w = new double[n];

                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        String C = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter x values");
                        String d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter y values");

                        if (!C.isEmpty() || !d.isEmpty()) {
                            j = Double.parseDouble(C);
                            x2[i] = j;
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X value: " + x2[i] + "");

                            k = Double.parseDouble(d);
                            y2[i] = k;
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y value: " + y2[i]);
                            String f = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter weights");
                            m = Double.parseDouble(f);
                            w[i] = m;
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Weight: " + w[i]);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning! Enter a valid number.");
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
    );
    // events fot the enter button (tab 3)
    enter3.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    n = Integer.parseInt(items3.getText());
                    x3 = new double[n];
                    y3 = new double[n];
                    v3 = new double[n];

                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        String C = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter x values");
                        String d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter y values");

                        if (!C.isEmpty() || !d.isEmpty()) {
                            j = Double.parseDouble(C);
                            x3[i] = j;
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X value: " + x2[i] + "");

                            k = Double.parseDouble(d);
                            y3[i] = k;
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Y value: " + y2[i]);

                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning! Enter a valid number.");
                        }


                    }

                }
            }

    );
    // events for tha calculate button (tab 1)
    calcola1.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    calculateols(x1, y1);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delta: " + delta);

                    if(delta <= 0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occurred. Delta is an invalid value.");
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A: " + A);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B: " + B);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The line parameters are: " + String.format("%04f", A) + "(+)" + String.format("%04f", B) + "x");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A error: " + errA);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B error: " + errB);

                    }
                }
            }


    );
    // events for the compatibility button (tab 1)
    comp1.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Chi(x1, y1);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chi: " + chi);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chi/dof: " + redchi);
                }
            }
    );
    // events for tha calculate button (tab 2)
    calcola2.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    calculatewols(x2, y2, w);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delta :" + delta);
                    if(delta <= 0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occurred. Delta is an invalid value.");
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A: " + A);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B: " + B);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The line parameters are: " + String.format("%04f", A) + "(+)" + String.format("%04f", B) + "x");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A error: " + werrA);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B error: " + werrB);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    // events for the compatibility button (tab 2)
    comp2.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Chiw(x2, y2);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chi: " + chi);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chi/dof: " + redchi);
                }
            }
    );
    // events for tha calculate button (tab 3)
    calcola3.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    calculatepar(x3, y3);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "a: " + a);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "b: " +b);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "c:" + c);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The curve parameters are: " + String.format("%04f", a) + "(+)" + String.format("%04f", b) + "x"+"(+)"+String.format("%04f", c)+"x^2");

                }
            }
    );

    // events for cancel button (first tab)
    canc1.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    txts.setText("");
                    items1.setText("");
                    n = 0;
                     x1 = null;
                    y1 = null;
                }

            }

    );
    // events for cancel button (second tab)
    canc2.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    items2.setText("");
                    n = 0;
                    x2 = null;
                    y2 = null;
                    w = null;
                }
            }
    );
    // events for cancel button (third tab)
    canc3.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    items3.setText("");
                    n = 0;
                    x3 = null;
                    y3 = null;
                }
            }
    );


    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}

// interpolates data through the ordinary least squares method
private void calculateols(double x[], double y[]) {


    for (double w : x)
        sumx += w;

    for (double w : y)
        sumy += w;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        sumxy += x[i] * y[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        sumx2 += Math.pow(x[i], 2);
    }


    delta = (n * sumx2) - (Math.pow(sumx, 2));
    A = ((sumx2 * sumy) - (sumx * sumxy)) / delta;
    B = ((n * sumxy) - (sumx * sumy)) / delta;


    errA = sigma * (Math.pow(sumx2 / delta, 0.5));
    errB = sigma * (Math.pow(n / delta, 0.5));



}

// calculates the compatibility between interpolated data and measured (input) data
private void Chi(double X[], double Y[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        chi += (Math.pow((Y[i] - A - (B * X[i])), 2)) / (Math.pow(sigma, 2));
    }

    redchi = chi / (X.length - 2);
}

// interpolates data through the weighted ordinary least squares method
private void calculatewols(double wx[], double wy[], double W[]) {


    for (int i = 0; i < W.length; i++) {
        sumw += W[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wx.length; i++) {
        wsumx += w[i] * wx[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wx.length; i++) {
        wsumy += w[i] * wy[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wx.length; i++) {
        wsumxy += w[i] * wx[i] * wy[i];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < wx.length; i++) {
        wsumx2 += w[i] * (Math.pow(wx[i], 2));
    }


    delta = (sumw * wsumx2) - (Math.pow(wsumx, 2));
    A = ((wsumx2 * wsumy) - (wsumx * wsumxy)) / delta;
    B = ((sumw * wsumxy) - (wsumx * wsumy)) / delta;


    werrA = (Math.pow(wsumx2 / delta, 0.5));
    werrB = (Math.pow(sumw / delta, 0.5));


}
//  checks compatibility (as before)
private void Chiw(double X[], double Y[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        chi += (Math.pow((Y[i] - A - (B * X[i])), 2)) * w[i];
    }

    redchi = chi / (X.length - 2);
}

// interplates non linear date through the ordinary least squares method
private void calculatepar(double v1[], double v2[]) {
    for (double z : v1)
        sumv1 += z;
    for (double z : v2)
        sumv2 += z;

    double avrx = sumv1 / n;
    double avry = sumv2 / n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        v3[i] = (v1[i] - avrx);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumv32 += Math.pow(v3[i], 2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumv34 += Math.pow(v3[i], 4);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumv3v2 += v3[i] * v2[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumv32y += (Math.pow(v3[i], 2))*v2[i];
    }

    c = ((n*sumv32y)- (sumv2*sumv32))/((n*sumv34)-(Math.pow(sumv32, 2)));
    b = sumv3v2/sumv32;
    a = ((sumv2*sumv34)-(sumv32*sumv32y))/((n*sumv34)-(Math.pow(sumv32, 2)));
}
```

}

Comment: This is way too much code for a [mcve], you need to narrow your problem down to a specific section (ideally by debugging it). Also that huge amount of member variables is *very* likely to be related to your issues

Comment: You need to start trimming this example until the error goes away. Then you will know what is causing the problem and you can probably fix it. This debugging strategy is a necessary skill for any professional developer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try to debug it piece by piece until I find what's causing the error. Any tips for debugging? Just to know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also, you should break down your code into logic or "model" (non-GUI) classes, and view (GUI) classes, and first debug them separately. Strive to make your GUI classes as "dumb" as possible so that all they do is get information from the user and report back the state of the model to the user.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing all key variables when your clear buttons are pressed. For example:

```
private void calculatepar(double v1[], double v2[]) {
    for (double z : v1)
        sumv1 += z;
    for (double z : v2)
        sumv2 += z;

    double avrx = sumv1 / n;
    double avry = sumv2 / n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        v3[i] = (v1[i] - avrx);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumv32 += Math.pow(v3[i], 2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumv34 += Math.pow(v3[i], 4);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumv3v2 += v3[i] * v2[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumv32y += (Math.pow(v3[i], 2)) * v2[i];
    }

    c = ((n * sumv32y) - (sumv2 * sumv32)) / ((n * sumv34) - (Math.pow(sumv32, 2)));
    b = sumv3v2 / sumv32;
    a = ((sumv2 * sumv34) - (sumv32 * sumv32y)) / ((n * sumv34) - (Math.pow(sumv32, 2)));
}
```

where do you clear sumv32, smv34....?

And if you don't clear these values, then when this method is called the summation will continue. I suggest that you strive to keep as many variables like this *local* to the method, and avoid class fields for variables that are only used within a method, since this way the variables will re-initialize each time the method is called.

And it's the same problem in your other calculation methods. So sumw and similar fields in all your calculation methods should all be *local* variables, declared and initialized within the method

So for example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MathUtils {
    // interpolates non linear date through the ordinary least squares method
    public static TripleValue calculatepar(double v1[], double v2[]) {
        int n = v1.length;
        if (n == 0 || n != v2.length) {
            // invalid values passed in; throw an exception here
            String message = String.format("For values v1: %s and v2: %s",
                    Arrays.toString(v1),
                    Arrays.toString(v2));
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
        }
        double sumv1 = 0;
        double sumv2 = 0;
        double avrx = sumv1 / n;
        double avry = sumv2 / n;
        double[] v3 = new double[n];
        double sumv32 = 0;
        double sumv34 = 0;
        double sumv3v2 = 0;
        double sumv32y = 0;

        for (double z : v1)
            sumv1 += z;
        for (double z : v2)
            sumv2 += z;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            v3[i] = (v1[i] - avrx);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sumv32 += Math.pow(v3[i], 2);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sumv34 += Math.pow(v3[i], 4);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sumv3v2 += v3[i] * v2[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sumv32y += (Math.pow(v3[i], 2)) * v2[i];
        }

        double c = ((n * sumv32y) - (sumv2 * sumv32)) / ((n * sumv34) - (Math.pow(sumv32, 2)));
        double b = sumv3v2 / sumv32;
        double a = ((sumv2 * sumv34) - (sumv32 * sumv32y)) / ((n * sumv34) - (Math.pow(sumv32, 2)));

        return new TripleValue(a, b, c);
    }

    // other calculation methods go here
}
```

```
// class to hold one set of values returned in the method above
public class TripleValue {
    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;

    public TripleValue(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public double getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public double getC() {
        return c;
    }

}
```

Notes

- The variable names above should be changed so that they make sense and make the code self-commenting.
- I'm not sure what you're wanting to do with the `avry` variable since it does not appear to be used in your calculations.
- No need to have an `n` field since the double array lengths should hold this value.
- I have only shown one extracted method, but you'd do something like this for all extracted methods.
- Safer for the calculation methods to return a result rather than set fields as a side effect. Then the calling code would use the returned value(s) as needed.

Comment: I thought that clearing the arrays that stored the data used in the method was enough to stop summation or other calculations. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @philoez98: it's the same problem in your other calculation methods. So `sumw` and similar fields should all be ***local*** variables, declared and initialized **within** the method.

Comment: That's perfect, right now the code is working. I'm going to change those things you've told me to for a better code. Thank you for all the help.